# Plotting functions with SageMath, not Showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, sage

I have a problem where functions that I plot within SageMath aren't visually showing up. Even if I copy and paste code from the SageMath info pages, certain functions will not show up plotted for me. I'm using SageMath 8.1 Notebook. Here's example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
myPlot = plt.plot(np.array([0, 1, 2, 5]))
show(myPlot)
```

Output:

`[Line2D(-line49)]`

Instead of a graph. As far as I can tell, this should output a visual graph rather than just the info in brackets.

Some code I copy from the [SageMath Help Pages](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/plotting.html#plotting-functions-in-2d) works, such as:

```
v = [(1/cos(-pi/2+pi*i/100), tan(-pi/2+pi*i/100)) for i in range(1,200) if i!=100 ]
L = [(a/(a^2+b^2), b/(a^2+b^2)) for a,b in v]
```

Which outputs a visual graph.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib objects are not yet sufficiently integrated into Sage to be shown within a Sage notebook. You can save them, however.

```
myPlot = plt.plot([1, 3, 2, 4])
plt.savefig('myPlot.png')
```

But there is no need to involve matplotlib or NumPy directly, Sage has its own plotting functions (possibly using matplotlib under the hood).

```
myPlot = line(zip(range(4), [0, 1, 2, 5]))
show(myPlot)
```

I used `zip` because Sage's `line` needs input as `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ... ]`. It could be directly entered as `line([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 5)])`.

Comment: (a) Indeed, Sage's plotting functions do use matplotlib.

(b) Use `line(enumerate([0, 1, 2, 5]))` instead of the `zip` and `range` trick.